# Is there any specific reason why one might choose not to commit the .gitignore file to a Git repository?

Tags: git, github, version-control, gitignore

I'm currently working on a project and I've noticed that some repositories don’t include the .gitignore file in their commits. This got me wondering whether there are specific circumstances under which it is advisable not to commit the .gitignore file. Are there scenarios or best practices that recommend excluding the .gitignore file from commits, or is it generally advisable to always include it?

Comment: It's always best to include the .gitignore, but not everyone takes the time to do it.

Comment: If you don't see a `.gitignore` file in a repo, then it just doesn't have one. A file that is not committed does not exist in the repo, and not every repo contains a `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

Most projects contain a `.gitignore` file in the repo.  The best practices are to ignore files using the checked-in `.gitignore` file for any build artifacts that the project or its tooling (e.g., linters) typically builds, but not things which are developer specific.  Things which are developer specific typically go in the user's personal ignore file (usually `~/.config/git/ignore`), since I use Neovim, someone else might use Emacs, and a third person might use VS Code, and it's much easier to globally ignore your files rather than make every project learn about every editor.

For example, if you have a Rust project, you'll typically ignore the `target/` directory in the project, since that's where build products are, but an Emacs user would ignore all of the files ending in `~` in their personal ignore file, since those are Emacs products.

However, there are projects that literally never have any build products in the tree because the build has to happen outside of the tree.  For example, many CMake projects require a separate build directory, which you can call anything you want or place almost anywhere.  In that case, there's no build products anywhere and thus no need for a `.gitignore`.